# Is it possible to use the GearVR trackpad to move around environment?

Tags: aframe

Hi I'm really struggling to find an answer to this, I've made a basic 3D environment which the user can move around. However inside GearVR by default it doesn't appear like you can move around the environment, only turn to look on a fixed axis.

Is there anyway this is achievable either by using the trackpad on GearVR or a bluetooth controller?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried the latest update, but check out this component --

https://github.com/chenzlabs/gearvr-controls

Answer (score 0):

The set of locomotion constraints of GearVR are the same as for mobile/polyfill. Common options include A-Frame [checkpoint-controls, touch-controls](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls) for teleporting via gaze or tap to move.